# rpm + rpm -ba Build the source

Tags: rpm

when I perfrom rpm -ba /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/my_spec.spec

as described here
the output not include the Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.rpm
please advice why?

remark under /usr/src/redhat/RPMS I not see the test.sh-6.2-2.rpm

```
 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES]#  rpm -ba   /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/my_spec.spec
 Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /var/tmp/test.sh
 Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
```

my spec file

```
Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
Name: test.sh
Version: 6.2
Release: 2
Source:/root/test.sh
Group: Development/Debuggers
BuildRoot:/var/tmp/test.sh
License: OtherLicense
%description
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with rpmbuild command. I dont think rpm has an "-ba" option.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the version of RedHat or CentOS linux that you're using. `rpm -ba` option was removed from `rpm` many years ago. So, presuming you're using RHEL 5.x or CentOS 5.x or later, you need to use `rpmbuild` command to build your RPMs

**However**: It appears you're following some kind of a book or manual in your rpm study. This source of information is very outdated if it suggests using `rpm -ba` to build RPMs. I think you'd better find a more recent book or manual, since RPM has evolved considerably in the recent years. You can start with [rpmbuild man page](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/rpmbuild.8.html) or see the [list of available documentation](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs) on RPM web site.

Answer (score 0):

The spec file seems broken, the build_root should be a directory. The source is a bare file name, not a full path. And so on.

Install rpm-build, that package provides a lot of infrastructure for creating RPMs. If you open xyz.spec in {x,}emacs, it opens a template (dunno for vim or such). The [Fedora RM guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/index.html) is mandatory reading. It helps to get a source package (select something simple, stand-aloneish like bison or even git; hopefully something you already know how to build) and dissect its source RPM.